# unable to create new project in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, path, permissions

i am not able to create new project in visual studio 2015. The error is access to path is denied
C:\Users\good\Documents\visual studio 2015\windowsapplication1\windowsapplication1' is denied.

Comment: Do you can browse to that directory using the Explorer?

Comment: yes but there are no folder naming windowsapplication1

Comment: here is the picture
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1wvS9uYe9-McEk1Y29PdzRkaW8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution run visual studio as administrator or

Open visual studio. Tools Menu | Options | Projects and Solutions | Check the checkbox "Save new projects when created".

Also, you can change projects location in same dialog. Change it to somewhere else like D:\VBProjects etc..

Comment: Didn't work for me. I keep dropping back to the 'New Project' dialog box when pressing 'OK'.

Comment: Re-installing did the job.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in Visual Studio 2017. I removed this folder to get it working again:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_4f8023be

- 15.0_4f8023be is a unique hexadecimal  number for my AppData, yours will be a different.

---

It might also work by just removing:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_4f8023be\privateregistry.bin

and that way you won't lose your settings and extensions.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is this:

I uninstalled Visual studio 2015 completely and then installed Visual studio 2015 with option for update 3 unchecked.

I guess update 3 can cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem while trying to create a project under a **virtual disk path** (created by command `SUBST`), so the solution for me was to create a project under a path the virtual disk path was referring to.